# connecting BLE with Unity doesn't work. (scan works.)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a trouble with connecting BLE devices with Unity.

Actually, scanning was successful.
But connecting doesn't work at all.

To use BLE in Unity, I made a plugin using Android Studio.

I don't know why
device.connectGatt(current_activity, false, gattClientCallback);
doesn't make my BLE peripheral device(Arduino Nano 33 BLE) connects even though it returns BluetoothGATT correctly.
The text "set ble_gatt : true" shows when I called
BLE.bleControllerObj.Call("connect", address); in Unity. (This calls connect function of plugin/)
However, the connection doesn't happen, i.e. the callback onConnectionStateChange isn't called at all. (I know because "Connection success!" doesn't appear.)
The strange thing is that after device.connectGatt(current_activity, false, gattClientCallback); executed, then the ble peripheral device stops advertising without connecting, so I can't scan the ble device by other apps before terminating Unity app. I guess connecting request is sent to the ble peripheral device.

(Here, BLE is the name of Unity script, and bleControllerObj is an AndroidJavaObject instance in Unity.)

Also, I checked my device and peripheral ble device can be connected with existing nRF Connect app.

Please let me know what I'm missing. Or should I upload my Unity script too?

Here is a full code of java plugin I used.

```
package com.example.ble;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class BLEcontroller {

    public static Activity current_activity;
    public static Context context;
    public static BLEcontroller instance;

    public BluetoothAdapter ble_adapter;
    public BluetoothLeScanner leScanner;
    public List<BluetoothDevice> scanned_devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    public boolean connected_ = false;
    public BluetoothGatt ble_gatt;
    public BluetoothManager ble_manager;

    private void showText(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public static BLEcontroller getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BLEcontroller();
            current_activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
            context = UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext();
        }

        instance.scanned_devices= new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

        return instance;
    }

    public void setContext(Activity _activity, Context _context){
        current_activity=_activity;
        context=_context;
    }

    public void init() {
        Log.e("Unity", "init start!!!" );
        ble_manager = (BluetoothManager) current_activity.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        ble_adapter = ble_manager.getAdapter();

        Toast.makeText(context, "init start and scanner : "+(leScanner!=null), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Unity", "init start and scanner : "+(leScanner!=null) );
        checkBLEAvailable();

        leScanner = ble_adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        if (!current_activity.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "BlE isn't supported.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (leScanner == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "scanner is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }




    private void checkBLEAvailable() {

        if (ble_adapter == null || !ble_adapter.isEnabled()) {
            showText("ble is disabled");
            requestEnableBle();
        }

        requestPermissions();
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void startScan() {
        showText("There were " + scanned_devices.size() + " devices");
        scanned_devices.clear();
        Log.e("Unity", "clear devices");
        if (leScanner == null) {
            showText("leScanner was null!");
            Log.e("Unity", "leScanner is null!");
        }
        Log.e("Unity", "startScan in java.");
        leScanner.startScan(mScanCallback);
        showText("start scan");

    }


    public int getScanned_devicesNum(){
        return scanned_devices.size();
    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        return connected_;
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getScanned_device(int i){
        return scanned_devices.get(i);
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void stopScan(){
        leScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        showText("scan stop.");
    }

    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            processResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                processResult(result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            showText("scanFailed with "+errorCode);
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        private void processResult(final ScanResult result) {
            boolean add_result=true;
            if(result.getDevice().getName()==null) {
                Log.e("Unity", "No device name");
                add_result = false;
            }
            for (BluetoothDevice device : scanned_devices){
                if (device.getAddress()==result.getDevice().getAddress()){
                    Log.e("Unity", "Already exists : " +device.getName());
                    add_result=false;
                }
            }
            if (add_result){
                scanned_devices.add(result.getDevice());
            }
            tidyUpScanned_devices();
        }
    };

    public void tidyUpScanned_devices(){
        ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i<scanned_devices.size(); i++){
            if (getDeviceIndex(arrayList, scanned_devices.get(i))==-1){
                arrayList.add(scanned_devices.get(i));
            }
        }
        scanned_devices.clear();
        scanned_devices=arrayList;
    }

    private int getDeviceIndex(List<BluetoothDevice> list, BluetoothDevice device){
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            if (device.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i).getAddress())){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void connect(String address) {
        if (!ble_adapter.isEnabled()) {
            showText("Turn on BLE");
            return;
        }

        for (BluetoothDevice device : scanned_devices) {
            if (device.getAddress().equals(address)) {
                showText(("try connecting device : " + address));
                disconnectGattServer();
                ble_gatt = device.connectGatt(current_activity, false, gattClientCallback);
                showText("set ble_gatt : " + (ble_gatt != null));
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void connect() {
        if (!ble_adapter.isEnabled()) {
            showText("Turn on BLE");
            return;
        }

        for (BluetoothDevice device : scanned_devices) {
            showText(("try connecting device : " + device.getAddress()));
            disconnectGattServer();
            ble_gatt = device.connectGatt(current_activity, false, gattClientCallback);
            showText("set ble_gatt : " + (ble_gatt != null));
            return;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void disconnectGattServer() {
        /*showText("Closing Gatt connection");
        // reset the connection flag
        connected_ = false;
        // disconnect and close the gatt
        if (ble_gatt != null) {
            ble_gatt.disconnect();
            ble_gatt.close();
        }*/
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    // Gatt Client Callback class
    private BluetoothGattCallback gattClientCallback=new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt _gatt, int _status, int _new_state) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(_gatt, _status, _new_state);
            showText("Connection Success!");
            if (_status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                showText("failed connecting");
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            }
            if (_new_state == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                // set the connection flag
                connected_ = true;
                showText("Connected to the GATT server");
                _gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (_new_state == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt _gatt, int _status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(_gatt, _status);
            // check if the discovery failed
            if (_status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                showText("Device service discovery failed, status: " + _status);
                return;
            }
            showText("service discovered : "+_gatt.getServices().get(0).getUuid());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt _gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic _characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(_gatt, _characteristic);

            showText( "characteristic changed: " + _characteristic.getValue().toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt _gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic _characteristic, int _status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(_gatt, _characteristic, _status);
            if (_status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                showText("Characteristic written successfully");
            } else {
                showText("Characteristic write unsuccessful, status: " + _status);
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                showText("Characteristic read successfully");
            } else {
                showText("Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: " + status);
            }
        }

        // Log the value of the characteristic
        // @param characteristic
        private void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic _characteristic) {
            byte[] msg = _characteristic.getValue();
            showText( "read: " + msg.toString());
        }
    };


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void requestEnableBle() {
        Intent ble_enable_intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        current_activity.startActivityForResult(ble_enable_intent, 1);

    }

    private void requestPermissions(){
        current_activity.requestPermissions(
                new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @JungJaeWoo I am working on something similar, but I get an error when I call activity.requestPermissions. "AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/app/ActivityCompat;" . I am setting the activity from unity  " AndroidJavaClass unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
                AndroidJavaObject activity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
                _pluginClass.SetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mainActivity", activity);. **any hint what is the issue?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

The problem was that I tried to use Toast method which should be used in UI thread, but the callback is actually called in binder thread, so the thread was terminated before starting discoverServices.

Also, be sure that connectGatt, disconnect, close should be run in the main thread, maybe in some devices, so using new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post is recommended.

> ConnectGatt must be called in ui thread on some kind of phones。In
> Android-BLE-Library ，BleManagerHandler::enqueue can be called in
> worker thread, BluetoothGattCallback::onConnectionStateChange is also
> called in binder thread . so this two condition could cause this
> issue!

(https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/issues/159)